# SQL Server 2005 select fields from a certain time frame

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime

Right now I'm using this command to retrieve all fields from the current day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [SecureOrders]
WHERE DateTime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
      AND 
      DateTime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 1)
```

However, I want to be able to get the fields that were entered between noon yesterday and noon today - how can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0.5 is noon (eg half a day)

```
WHERE DateTime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), -0.5)
      AND 
      DateTime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @NoonToday DATETIME;

SET @NoonToday = DATEADD(HOUR, 12, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP));

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [SecureOrders]
WHERE [DateTime] >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @NoonToday)
AND [DateTime] < @NoonToday;
```

Answer (score 0):

it might seem ugly but should work

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  [SecureOrders] 
WHERE 
  DateTime >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) - 0.5 AND DateTime < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 1) + 0.5
```

Comment: I recommend staying away from the implicit addition/subtraction operations for date/time types. They work fine in SQL Server 2005 but they are not compatible with the new types in SQL Server 2008 (which, it's feasible to imagine, many people will migrate to once they're off 2005). It's a little more typing but DATEADD is both more forward-compatible and the intent is much more clear.

Comment: agreed. let's leave this answer alive to prevent other from using it as the solution for sql server 2008 (and higher i believe)

Answer (score 0):

A variation on [@Aaron Bertrand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986963/sql-server-2005-select-fields-from-a-certain-time-frame/6987044#6987044)'s solution, without declaring a variable and without treating a non-zero integer value as a date:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SecureOrders o
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) * 24 + 12, 0)
  ) AS d (TodayNoon)
WHERE o.DateTime < d.TodayNoon
  AND o.DateTime >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, d.TodayNoon)
```

Comment: I don't see the problem with either of your comments, but ok. I also don't find a `CROSS JOIN` easier to understand... but whatever floats your boat. :-)

Comment: The idea behind not using an integer as a date is not to make assumptions about the internal representation of timestamps. The only exception is zero, which is used for rounding: this solution assumes that 0 represents a timestamp that points at the beginning of some day (whatever that day is). I thought it could be more consistent with what you said in a comment to heximal's question about staying away from implicit operations on dates. I.e. here I am not only avoiding implicit additions/subtractions, but also refraining from implicit conversions. :)

Comment: AFAIK `CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))` is the same as `DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))` - the former is performed as soon as you perform some other `DATEADD`. I get your point, but the integer math stuff breaks *now* in SQL Server 2008; the method I showed works fine even in Denali CTP3 - a contrived example: `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2(7), DATEADD(HOUR, 5, DATEDIFF(DAY, 2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)));` ... also not sure what is wrong with using a variable, I find it helps newer folks break things down and understand the parts better.

Comment: Nothing's wrong about variables, just wanted to show an alternative. I use both approaches depending on situation. As for the other point, I think I've understood you too: you do not mind converting numbers to dates implicitly as long as this conversion works consistently across various timestamp types (and in various versions of SQL Server). And even if I erred there, I would like to make it clear that I personally can see nothing wrong with either implicit conversion of ints to dates or direct maths on dates as long as one knows what one is doing.